# Can I change the color of the mortar in my brick wall?

Tags: concrete, brick, mortar

We recently built our home and the mortar color between the bricks is dark gray, we did not pay attention to it and because of that the brick face is looking duller due to the standard gray mortar.

We would like to put a lighter color a half-white or natural color is what we would like to go to.

How can we remedy this? Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted to, you could rake out the mortar and re-point with a coloured mortar of your choice.

That does seem a little excessive though, as you say it was recently built.

I'd be wary about using a stain, personally, for fear of also staining parts of the bricks.

Answer (score 1):

If the mortar does not have a sealer treatment on it, you can stain it.

Alternatively, some sealers with adhere to other sealers (or to unsealed mortar as intended) and are color treated which **can** (**can** not will, depends on the treatment) drastically change the color lighter/dark or colored.

Without harsh chemicals (safe for use outside but still more tedious and less safe for DIYers) you typically can't stain lighter, you question didn't specify what color you are trying to get to.